# Single image rectification software

Tags: image-processing, image-registration, photogrammetry

1. The idea is to rectify single photograph taken from perspective (its not an aerial image, so I cannot use ground control points).
2. Instead of GCPs, street furniture and distance between them will be measured in real life, therefore I'll know some true measurements and distances.
3. The photograph will be taken once a month to see if any changes occurred, therefore, ideally compared with other images.
4. Once photo is (somehow)corrected from distortions and from perspective, I then need to extract basic dimensions. - a survey of some kind.

The attached is a sample image (Sea Wall) of what I can be given, - sea wall (fixed, so I be able to collect real measurements), and gravel, where gravel needs to be measured (increase or decrease of it)

Ideally I'm looking for a free and simple software but, I'm open to any ideas.

[Sea Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pu3J.jpg)

Comment: Mmmm... good luck with measuring anything off that astonishingly low quality image!

Comment: It was just an example. I will have better quality pictures

Answer (score 0):

Photogrammetric image rectification from cad-kas seems to do it.( i have not tried myself and it is not free!):
Rectify photos with the help of photogrammetry. So you get a completely level view of one side of a building for example.
So you can take the result for measurements of this building. You can export the result as picture or as DXF file. If you take a photo of a rectangle what you get is a trapezoid.
https://www.cadkas.com/photogrammetric-image-rectification.php